# reactstrap <UncontrolledDropdown> is rending out of viewport, mr/ml-auto and float-right/left not working

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, reactstrap

Essentially, I have a `<UncontrolledDropdown>` that when expanded is going out of the view port so it can't be viewed.

[image: Dropdown]

I have tried various methods to get it to dropdown to the left and not the right, but they have not worked. For example, `.mr-auto`, `.ml-auto`, `.float-left`, and `.float-right`.

Here is the HTML and the SCSS for the element:

```
<UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar>
    <DropdownToggle className='custom-toggle' nav>
        <Button  color='primary'>
        <i className="far fa-user"></i>
        </Button>
    </DropdownToggle>
    <DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownItem>
            Account Settings
        </DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem divider />

        <Link to='/auth/signout' className='signout'>
            <DropdownItem>
                Sign Out
                <i className='fas fa-power-off float-right'>
                </i>
            </DropdownItem>
        </Link>

    </DropdownMenu>
</UncontrolledDropdown>
```

---

```
nav {

    .custom-nav-link {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .custom-toggle {
        padding-right: 0 !important;

        button {
            width: 56px;
            height: 40px;

            i {
                margin-top: 3px;
                font-size: 20px;
            }
        }

        @media all and (max-width: 767px) {
            button {
                width: 100%;
                height: 40px;
            }
        }
    }

    .signout {
        button {
            color: $red;

            i {
                margin-top: 3px;
            }

            &:hover, &:focus, &:active {
                background-color: $red;
                color: #FFFFFF;
                outline: none;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Suggestions for how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try aligning your dropdown menu direction:

```
<DropdownMenu right> 
  ...
```

Comment: Ah man right there in the documentation plain as day... https://reactstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/. Thanks for bringing it to my attention!