# React Navbar dropdown outside the page

Tags: css, reactjs

How can I automatically calculate the `reactstrap` Dropdown to be displayed inside the page?

I created the user helper component to display a user icon at the top right corner of my navbar.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
 import { Dropdown, DropdownToggle, DropdownMenu } from 'reactstrap';
 import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

 import IntlMessages from '../Util/IntlMessages';
 
const User = () => {
    const [userDropdownMenu, setUserDropdownMenu] = useState(null);
    
    const toggleUserDropdownMenu = () => {
        setUserDropdownMenu(!userDropdownMenu);
    }
 
    return (
        <Dropdown
            isOpen={userDropdownMenu}
            toggle={() => toggleUserDropdownMenu()}
        >
            <DropdownToggle
                tag="div"
                className="d-flex align-items-center"
            >
                <div className="user-profile">
                    <img
                        src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/avatars/profile.jpg`}
                        alt="user profile"
                        className="img-fluid rounded-circle"
                        width="35"
                        height="85"
                    />
                </div>
            </DropdownToggle>
            <DropdownMenu>
            <ul className="list-unstyled mb-0">
                <li className="p-15 border-bottom user-profile-top bg-primary rounded-top">
                    <p className="text-white mb-0 fs-14">User Name</p>
                    <span className="text-white fs-14">email@example.com</span>
                </li>
                <li className="p-10">
                    <Link to={{
                        pathname: '/app/users/user-profile-1',
                        state: { activeTab: 0 }
                    }}>
                        <i className="zmdi zmdi-account text-primary mr-3"></i>
                        <span><IntlMessages id="widgets.profile" /></span>
                    </Link>
                </li>
                <li className="p-10 border-top">
                    <a href="!#" onClick={(e) => alert(e)}>
                        <i className="zmdi zmdi-power text-danger mr-3"></i>
                        <span><IntlMessages id="widgets.logOut" /></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </DropdownMenu>
        </Dropdown>
    );
 }
 
 export default User;
```

However, when I open it. it is displayed outside the browser (image below)
[image]

Comment: Try following this  answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49042837/7430118

Comment: Thank you @bonnopc. I had to add the ```UncontrolledDropdown``` and align the ```DropdownMenu ```.